# Atualizar o console sem ficar piscando C++

Tags: c++, jogos

Olá, estou fazendo um jogo da cobrinha, o jogo já está finalizado, porém, creio que pela alta frequência de `system("cls")`, o console fica piscando, e queria saber como arrumar isso

Aqui minha void com o desenho:

```
void Draw(){            //Void com todo o Draw;
    system("cls");
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < largura+2; i++)              //Printa primeira linha
        cout << "#";

    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < altura; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < largura; j++){

            obsPos = false;             //Seta obsPos como falso

            for(int q = 0; q < obsQuantidade; q++){
                if(obstaculoY[q] == i && obstaculoX[q] == j){           //Verifica se o obstaculo está naquela posição, caso esteja obsPos é setado para true;
                        obsPos = true;
                }
            }

            if(j == 0)                 //Printa paredes
                cout << "#";


            if (i == y && j == x){          //Printa cabeça da cobra
                setConsoleColour(DARK_GREEN);
                cout << "O";
                setConsoleColour(WHITE);

            }

            else if (i == FRUTAY && j == FRUTAX)      //Printa fruta
            {
                setConsoleColour(BRIGHT_RED);
                cout << "*";
                setConsoleColour(WHITE);
            }

            else if(obsPos == true){            //Printa o obstaculo com a condição do obsPos como true
                cout << "@";
            }


            else{
                bool printar = false;               //Criando variavel para dar print no corpo da cobra
                for(int k = 0; k < rabo; k++){
                    if(tailX[k] == j && tailY[k] == i){        //Para cada vez que o k for menor que o valor do rabo verificar se ele é igual a um espaço da cobra
                        setConsoleColour(BRIGHT_GREEN);
                        cout << "o";                    //Caso seja printa "o"
                        setConsoleColour(WHITE);
                        printar = true;                 //Caso não coloca variavel printar como true
                    }
                }

                if(!printar){            //Caso printar seja falso coloca espaço em branco
                    cout << " ";
                }

            }

            if(j == largura-1)                  //Printa paredes da direita
                cout << "#";

            }
        cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Cara, eu acho que não tem como - afinal, tu estás usando o console para imprimir caracteres. Se isso te incomoda, tens que usar uma biblioteca gráfica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `system("cls")` é um grande problema para todos os [iniciantes que querem fazer um joguinho no console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842526/update-console-without-flickering-c), pois o uso do `system` já é algo [perigoso](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/) como também o uso da função `cls` é péssimo nesse caso, pois ela é lenta somado ao ser uma função do system que também é pesada, por isso conseguimos ver a tela "piscando" com facilidade quando precisamos repetir ele varias vezes.

Entretanto, é possível sim evitar esse problema e conseguir fazer seu jogo funcionar, apesar de não perfeito, existem muitos métodos, inclusive de bibliotecas, que [solucionariam seu problema](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/) como a conio.h e a curses.h, porém **a escolha desses métodos depende de que tipo de limpeza de tela ou atualização de quadro você deseja fazer**, nesse exemplo de um jogo da cobrinha creio que o melhor método e o menos datado de todos seria:

- Montar o console como se fosse duas matriz com tamanhos que você precisar, a buffer e a frameAtual
- Criar uma classe que guarda a matriz buffer(o frame que fica na tela), e a matriz  frameAtual(que guarda as informações mais recentes), junto das posições do player(que pode ser facilmente adaptado para uma cobrinha) e então com os métodos de movimentar o player, checar e atualizar a tela.
- O método de atualização seletiva ira rodar um `for` rodando por toda a tela checando quais a diferenças entre o buffer e o frameAtual e passando as diferenças para tela em tempo real, depois atualizando o buffer de verdade, isso funciona exatamente pois **a parte lenta de limpar o console não é o código em sí, é a velocidade de I/O do console do windows, que é muito baixa**, então centenas de ifs e um update seletivo acabam sendo muito mais rápido e agradável aos olhos que limpar tudo e refazer.

Fiz um protótipo beem simplista com isso em prática para você usar de base para essa ideia usando apenas um 'A' de player, é um método perfeito para um jogo estilo cobrinha ou tetris, então creio que seja o mais ideal apesar de você precisar adaptar ou reescrever muita coisa que você já tem pronta:

```
#include <iostream> // acabei usando printf nas coisas por que dizem que é mais rápido kk
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>  //kbhit

#define screenWidth 70
#define screenHeight 30

#define KEY_UP 80
#define KEY_DOWN 72
#define KEY_RIGHT 77
#define KEY_LEFT 75

using namespace std;

void ShowConsoleCursor(bool showFlag);
void setCursorPosition(int x, int y);

class game {
    //Frame atual e frame buffer
    char frameAtual[screenWidth][screenWidth], buffer[screenWidth][screenWidth];
    char Player;
    int plX, plY;
        
    public:
        //Inicia a posição do player na tela e seta os dois frames como vazio
        void Init() {
            Player = 'A';
            plX = 20; plY = 20;
            for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
                    frameAtual[x][y] = buffer[x][y] = ' ';
                }
            }
            frameAtual[plX][plY] = Player;
        }
        void MainL() {
            bool loop = true;
            DrawAll();
            while (loop == true) {
                UpdateBuffer();
                Move();
                SelDraw();
            }
        }
    private:
        //função bem simples para registrar o movimento
        void Move() {
            char keyPressed;
            if (kbhit()) {
                keyPressed = getch();

                switch(keyPressed){ //esse switch analisa qual tecla foi digitada
                    case KEY_UP: // Seta para cima
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = ' ';
                        plY += 1;
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = Player;
                    break;
                        
                    case KEY_DOWN: // Seta para baixo
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = ' ';
                        plY -= 1;
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = Player;
                    break;
                    
                    case KEY_RIGHT: // Seta para direita
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = ' ';
                        plX += 1;
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = Player;
                    break;
                    
                    case KEY_LEFT: // Seta para esquerda
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = ' ';
                        plX -= 1;
                        frameAtual[plX][plY] = Player;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        //primeira função de criar a tela vazia
        void DrawAll() {
            for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
                    printf("%c", frameAtual[x][y]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        //Atualização de frame seletivo - Checa as diferenças no buffer e no frame atual e corrige elas
        void SelDraw() {
            for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
                    if (frameAtual[x][y] != buffer[x][y]) {
                        setCursorPosition(x,y); printf("%c", frameAtual[x][y]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        //Atualizar o buffer setando oq está no frame mais recente nele
        void UpdateBuffer() {
            for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
                    buffer[x][y] = frameAtual[x][y];
                }
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    
    ShowConsoleCursor(false);
    
    game g;
    g.Init();
    g.MainL();
    return 0;
}
//Tirar o cursor da tela (opcional)
void ShowConsoleCursor(bool showFlag)
{
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO     cursorInfo;

    GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
    cursorInfo.bVisible = showFlag;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
}
//Pode ser um gotoxy ou qualquer outra função para manipular a posição do cursor 
void setCursorPosition(int x, int y)
{
    static const HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    std::coutflush();
    COORD coord = { (SHORT)x, (SHORT)y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, coord);
}
```